# ajaxForm uploadProgress doesn't work with my upload method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know that there is many posts about this topic on stack overflow but none of them didn't helped me.

I've tried some methods that I've found but none of them works. First is:

```
$(function() {

        var bar = $('#progress-bar');

        $('#uploadMedia').ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
            },
            complete: function(xhr) {
                console.log('done' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

I've set a 40mb video to upload but my progress bar fills in 1 second to 100%. I'm using laravel framework and I think that's maybe because my upload method starts with $user = Sentinel::getUser(); and that uploadProgress thinks that's it and set progress bar to 100%.

I'm not very familiar with jquery, ajax.

Thank you all in advance and best regards.

Comment: If you are testing with localhost, then it may happen that file would get uploaded very quickly.

Comment: I'm testing on localhost but even if progress bar goes to 100% upload didn't finished

Comment: I would recommend to look around (google or SO) because this is very common task and you would definitely find a solution.

Comment: I've already tried that but I will keep finding

Comment: what happen when you add `console.log(percentVal);` to the `uploadProgress` callback? Do you see multiple updates?

Comment: Plus, if you're using Edge (That crappy replacement for IE) then it looks like there's a bug with `uploadProgress` https://github.com/jquery-form/form/issues/525

Comment: I'm not using Edge, I was testing on Chrome and Firefox. I get multiple updated but in second(etc. 43% than 100%)

Comment: Well then if you get `43` in the console then it look like it's just the fact that you trying it on localhost (Unless there's a major delay between the time the `uploadProgress` gets to 100, until the actual upload complete. You can try and add `var bar = $('#progress-bar').css('transition', 'width .6s ease');` so it will make the progress changes a bit more "animated"

Comment: There is really little delay(less than second) between 43 and 100